# Public Private Domain Settings on,- Allow an App through Windows Firewall,- for this what are the best powershell cmdlets available in Windows 10

Tags: powershell, cmd, netsh, windows-defender

Picture while its been prompted,-

[image]

While it used happens, somehow for my login, administrative rights had some restriction, so however the way I progress with `Microsoft Key -> X` and go made `cmd` or so from `powershell` that had `Administrative rights` I couldn't find commands which are in appropriation to do this setting on,- ***Public Private Domain Settings on,- Allow an App through Windows Firewall***

So what are those right `cmdlets` and `args`.

I am able to do, run these commands by, something on for different programs with this I am able to sustain my `deletion & addition of entries`, as I am not allowed to do any tick for any of this such options ***Public Private Domain*** later, as my any answer to the ***Dialog Box*** depicted & attached over this feed, makes complete regret with new entry on with no tick marks for `Public Private Domain` for including the one for the `App`

> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Java 8 Update 221" dir=in
>   action=allow program="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe"
>   enable=yes
>
> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Java(TM) Platform SE binary"
>   dir=in action=allow program="c:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe" enable=yes
>
> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Java 8 Update 202" dir=in
>   action=allow program="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe"
>   enable=yes

What are the other options in `cmdlets` in place `netsh` on `cmd`

Here are the `coammnds` *rules* for deletion for the complete app, from entry list.

> ## Deleltion
>
> netsh advfirewall firewall Delete rule name="Google Chrome"
>
> netsh advfirewall firewall Delete rule name="Java(TM) Platform SE
>   binary"
>
> netsh advfirewall firewall Delete rule name="Java 8 Update 221"
>
> netsh advfirewall firewall Delete rule name="jmc"

Comment: When you add a firewall rule, why not use the `profile=domain`, `profile=public`, `profile=private`, or `profile=any`? You can use the set command to go back later and set the option as well: `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule`.

Comment: I am unaware those possibilities, and still I am curious is there any `powershell` - `cmdlet` by which we can do this. _Allow an App through Windows Firewall_ boycotts me by disabling entry in its `Dialog Box`, however so with `Administrative Rights`, its stating that I may need this to perform complete action. Not sure of what blocks, any policies or so. Thanks for quick directions. It really helps me for immediate referrals. Thanks :)